# Best way to store three type bits?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, sqlite

What is the best way to store and query **three different type information**?

for example:

> **YES / NO / NO COMMENT**

do i need to store these datas as integer? (e.g. 1,2,3) or not?

i will use sqlite for local data and sync it with mssql server periodically.

Comment: A nullable bit type can have three values: 0, 1, or NULL.

Comment: using "NULL" as a data is safe? can it be usefull when selecting datas?

Comment: No, "null" typically means "unknown" in SQL

Comment: For a tri-state boolian (yes, no, not-specified), NULL is perfectly fine. You can select all rows where the value IS NULL (don't use an equal sign). What you can't do is join on another table like you would with an actual value. But you can certainly query for all rows there there is NO COMMENT.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bit field and have yes/no/no comment in the mssql database as true/false/null, however sqlite has no special boolean field and you will need to use an integer field. My suggestion would be to use 1/0/null in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do it "by the book" you should have a "responses" table like this:

```
+--------+----------------+
| id     | name           |
+--------+----------------+
| 0      | yes            |
| 1      | no             |
| 2      | no comment     |
+--------+----------------+
```

and use the id (probably integer) as a foreign key there where you need it.

This way, your RDBMS can preserve *referential integrity*.

But in actuality, most people use a single character for that, like `'Y'`, `'N'`, `'C'`.

Also, nothing prevents you from having a single character as the key of the "responses" table, though in my experience not many opt for this solution.